# How to use Ajax with JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2

I want to implement Ajax on my JSF web project. I googled and found that ICEFaces is supporting Ajax with JSF. Yet I dont know the usability of it.

Any one has experience Ajax/JSF, please guide me where to move.

[EDIT]

If any one has experienced on similar, please share the usability as well.
the good and bad..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSF 2.0 has built-in support for Ajax using the f:ajax tag. All three of ICEFaces, OpenFaces, and RichFaces also have Ajax-enabled components but with JSF 2.0 it is now possible to add Ajax to your apps without using third-party libraries. IBM has a series of nice tutorials in this regards: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?search_by=JSF+2+fu

Comment: Oh great! Is JSF's built in Ajax support powerful like ICEFaces, OpenFaces or RichFaces? or it has limitaion or difficulty compare to others?

Comment: It's powerful but JSF 2.0 does not have a rich set of Ajax-enabled components. So if you find out that you need an Ajax-enabled component that JSF 2.0 does not have it already, you'll need to use a third-party component library. I myself like OpenFaces a lot, but RichFaces and ICEFaces are also great libraries.

Comment: Can I work with both built-in and a third party at the same time in a single application? is it possible?

Comment: @Muneer: Yes, you can absolutely do that.

Comment: If I am using any framework like Spring web or something, Do I have the Ajax support without Openface/iceface?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest - [Pro JSF and Ajax: Building Rich Internet Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595807)

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 has built in basic AJAX functionality through the f:ajax tag.

David Geary shows how in part 3 of his jsf-fu articles.  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/index.html

Comment: Can you suggest me which one is easy to use? Is built in one more developer friendly than 3rd party?

Comment: Which one?  I do not understand - this is in the standard JSF 2.0 present in Java EE 6, without any extra downloads.  See the linked articles for how to use it.

Comment: yes Trorobjorn, I was asking about the easiness of usage in both third party Ajax libraries and built-in Ajax library.

Comment: Start with the one in JEE6, it is simple and may be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple and elegant to use Ajax in JSF but you should not abuse because of debugging constraints.

HTML page Fragment :

```
 <h:commandLink  value="tab 1">
    <f:param name="tabIndex" value="1" />
    <f:ajax event="click" render=":contentForm" listener="#{tabBB.handleTabChange}"/>
 </h:commandLink>
```

Backing bean fragment :

```
public boolean handleTabChange() {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String index = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("tabIndex");
    setTabIndex(Integer.parseInt(index));
    return true;
}
```