# Where does JSF validate the input values? Back-End or Front-end?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

JSF can validate the input values. Can anybody say where JSF validates..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF2 Validation Clientside or Serverside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013410/jsf2-validation-clientside-or-serverside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both answers are a bit unclear, therefore I would like to summarize:

1.) JSF as it is, **always performs the validation on server side**! Validation in JSF is a part of JSF component lifecycle. The life-cycle is triggered when you submit some data. I do not want to go in details but the life-cycle goes through the phsaes (Restore the component, trigger conversions, validate the converted values, execute actionlisteners and actions, render the reponse)

2.) The validation that feels like client-site validation is when you use ajax support in JSF. What this method does is that it requests the execution of only some html fields. JSF performs the same life-cycle as for the ordinary requests. The difference is that it converts and validates only the components you specify, and renders the output only for components you specified. **Therefore, ajax supported validation in JSF is also preformed on the server-side!**

3.) I have to disagree that third-party libraries provide client-side validation.

**Primefaces** integrates jQuery UI, but it still uses the ajax aproach to validate data. You can write your own jQuery JS to validate certain field, but I would not do it. It is painful to write and hard to manage duplicated validation logic.

**Richfaces** provides partial client-side validation. It provides JS implementation for some of the JSR 303 and JSF validators. Therefore, real client-side JS validation is provided, but only for the validators for which JS implementation exists. See: http://planet.jboss.org/post/richfaces_4_client_side_validation

**Ice faces** as being a Primefaces clone do not provide client-side validation.

Answer (score 3):

Server always and client sometimes.

The client may validate certain types of input using HTML/Javascript as a usability enhancement. However that and all other input will always be validated on the server when the client posts information back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow up to @Mike Q, JSF can do validation either on client side or server side.  However, built into JSF lifecycle (which takes place on the server side) is a validation phase.  It is possible for a component to not have server side validation, but that is not recommended .  All of the standard components provide server side validation.

JSF Components can also provide client side validation.  Many of the third-party JSF component libraries ([PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/), [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces), ...) provide this.

Comment: "Client side" validation in JSF component libraries is more than often just server side validation which is performed by ajax which simulates a very quick "client side" experience.