# Accept text or characters in lower case

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I am using JSF2.0, Spring 3 and Hibernate 4.

Is it possible in jsf to enter text or characters in inputText in either upper case or lower case? I mean even if user enters in upper case, inputText  should always accept characters in lower case.

Is this possible in JSF 2?

Thanks

Comment: can't you just call **String.toLowerCase()** in the backing bean if you want to just convert an uppercase character to lowercase ??

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Yes it is possible, was wondering whether in JSF any such client validations exists or not?

Comment: In pure JSF you have to validate it in server side, as the first answer says. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4014119/1199132 If you want client-side validation you'll have to use your own javascript.

Comment: However you can take a look to third-party component libraries as Primefaces or Richfaces, maybe you can find something already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to automatically transform the input; see the Java EE 6 [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjcut.html) for more.

```
@FacesConverter("lowerConverter")
public class LowerConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext cx, UIComponent component,
                              String value) throws ConverterException {
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Locale locale = cx.getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
        return value.toLowerCase(locale);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext cx, UIComponent component,
                              Object value) throws ConverterException {
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: McDowell How do I refer this in JSF page?

Comment: @Polppan did you check link to Java EE 6 tutorial?

Comment: Use the [converter attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/inputText.html) on the input field. `converter="lowerConverter"`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own validator to validate text case. Check [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javaserver-faces-jsf-validation-tutorial-error-handling-jsf-validator/) tutorial. But it's not client side validation - request will be sent to server and if it's not valid page will be reloaded and show validation error message.

Comment: Actually, what he needs is a converter, a validator is used to fulfil a different need

Comment: @kolossus it's probably true. But there is a possibility that someone wants to make users input only text in lower case, not convert it on server. You can't be sure.