# How to validate blank field on bean side in jsf?

Tags: validation, jsf

I have some input fields and some selectonemenu, I need to validate them and based on their validation I have to show a error message for whole page. I have to also show message with that inputfields and selectonemenu.

My validation is only for null and blank values. Since I want to show a message based upon null and blank fields I tried bean side validation. But my validation method is never called for blank fields.

Comment: Did you look in google? http://www.codereye.com/2009/12/validating-empty-text-field-using-jsf.html By the way, JSF always makes the validations in server side, for client side you need to use a third-party library or write your own javascript code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `required="true"` on the input components.

```
<h:inputText id="input" ... required="true" />
<h:message for="input" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="menu" ... required="true" />
<h:message for="menu" />
```

You are not very clear about "bean side", the terminology used in the question is very poor and overly generic, but if you actually meant JSR303 bean validation and expecting the `@NotNull` to be triggered, then you need to add the following context parameter to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way JSF will convert empty string submitted values to `null` before passing to model. The `@NotNull` will namely not kick in on empty strings.

#### See also:

- [Bean Validation @NotNull, @NotBlank and @NotEmpty does not work in JSF+Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545231/notnull-notblank-and-notempty-bean-validation-does-not-work-in-jsf)
- [JSF2 Validation Clientside or Serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013410/jsf2-validation-clientside-or-serverside/)

Comment: Thank you @BalusC for reply. I am sorry for using "bean side" terminology. I will definitely try it.