# change h:inputText attribute with javascript jsf2

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, input, converters

I have this input :

```
    <p:column headerText="Quantité">
        <h:inputText styleClass="maqte" id="qte"
            onkeyup="validerInput($(this),$(this).parent().prev().find('.monpu'));"
            value="#{car.qte}" converter="lenientDoubleConverter" >

        </h:inputText>
    </p:column>
```

as shown in code above (`converter="lenientDoubleConverter"`)
[I use this converter (to disable the implicit conversion of jsf2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204743/how-to-disable-default-jsf-validation-and-conversion-of-one-input-field)

but after when the user click on one button I want to enable it, then I should remove this converter with javascript before the request is sent to ther server

is there any way to remove this attribute with javascript

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *is there any way to remove this attribute with javascript*

No. Rightclick page and do *View Source* in your favourite browser. You'll see that JSF code produces one and all HTML code. The JSF component's `converter` attribute is nowhere represented in the generated HTML output of `<h:inputText>`. Even more, the converter doesn't run in client side at all. It's merely a server-side declaration and the converter runs in server side.

Your best bet is to let the button add a certain request parameter which instructs the converter to be non-lenient. E.g.

```
<p:commandButton ...>
    <f:param name="disableLenientDoubleConverter" value="true" />
</p:commandButton>
```

with

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    try {
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    } catch (ConverterException e) {
        if ("true".equals(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("disableLenientDoubleConverter"))) {
            throw e;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you BalusC, it works I tested with this : `<p:commandButton value="valider" process="@this lesarticles" actionListener="#{commandeMB.listener}" >
     <f:param name="disableLenientDoubleConverter" value="true" />
     </p:commandButton>` it launch the actionListener method only when conversion is done

Comment: but I have one problem : the `p:message` that I put with the inputText (inside datatable) does not show error : `<p:column headerText="Quantité">
   <h:inputText styleClass="maqte" id="qte"
    onkeyup="validerInput($(this),$(this).parent().prev().find('.monpu'));"
    value="#{car.qte}" converter="lenientDoubleConverter" required="true" converterMessage="double" >

   </h:inputText>
   <p:message for="qte" />
  </p:column>` I don't know why

Comment: You forgot to ajax-udpate the message. This is however a different problem. If you still stucks, press `Ask Question`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(element).removeAttr("converter");
```

Comment: This is jQuery, not JavaScript:)

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript actually ;). But I get what your point is.

Answer (score -1):

Just set empty value to this attribute.

```
document.getElementsById("qte").setAttribute("converter","");
```