# Avoid submitting whole page after html5-validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, primefaces

I have a primefaces commandButton in myForm which should submit only this specific form. If I do the form-validation with `form.checkValidity()` and it returns true, the whole page gets submitted. How can I avoid submitting the whole page and submit only the specified area?

```
    <p:commandButton
        action="#{registrationController.register}" onclick="regForm[0].checkValidity()"
        partialSubmit="true" process="regForm" update="regForm" 
        value="#{messages['register.registerbutton']}" />
```

Comment: You're only invoking `checkValidity()` and not returning its result. This is not a JSF problem.

Comment: @BalusC I return the result, but if the validation fails on an input the warning is not displayed

Comment: I think he means you don't do `onclick="return regForm[0].checkValidity()"`. And you cannot submit 'a whole page', only forms and a commandButton only submits **its** form, not other forms. So you have to improve the question by providing an [mcve], version info etc.

Comment: @BalusC @Kukeltje  As I said before, I do return the result now. The validation works fine, the problem is that the page gets reloaded after I submit the form when `checkValidity()` returns true

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't happen when you remove `onclick` altogether?

Comment: @BalusC If I remove onlick-event the warning-bubbles are not getting displayed and my action is not fired until all the required inputs are filled. The page ist not getting refresehed, only this specific form.
If I add the onclick-event, the warning-bubbles are displayed. However, if the validation is succesful the page is gettin reloaded and not only the specified form.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should submit an invalid form. I mean that you should submit a valid form. If that works the way you expect when `onclick` is removed, then the cause of your problem is in `checkValidity()` function itself, not in JSF/PrimeFaces.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, thats most likely the problem. Is there a solution to avoid this or maybe a workaround?