# inputMask automatic completion by loosing focus

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to define an xhtml time field in hours and minutes with "HHH:mm" format thanks to the following inputMask.

```
<p:inputMask id="time"
             value="#{task.time}"
             converter="#{myBean.timeConverter}"
             size="8"
             mask="999:99">
</p:inputMask>
```

The problem is if I put `012` and press "Enter" or unfocus the field, it is cleared and I don't know how to manage it. Moreover I would like to complete automatically the field with "0" in that case : getting `012:00` if i put `012` or `240:00` if I put `24`, etc.

Comment: Maybe this helps you [JSF Regex validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161040/how-to-validate-string-input-field-for-pattern-on-jsf-form). If adding zeros isn't relevant on server-side, I would do it in js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you want is `autoClear='false'`.

See the docs: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/inputmask?id=attributes

*autoClear -    Clears the field on blur when incomplete input is entered.*

That will stop it from clearing the field.  As for finishing the mask you will have to do that yourself with `onblur` Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly what I was looking for.