# How to Write following JS regular expression in JSF

Tags: jsf, url-validation

```
<h:outputText value=""/>
<h:panelGroup>
<h:outputText value="State &amp; City Geolocation URL "/>
<h:inputText id="URL" value="#{geolocationBean.geolocationURL}" required="true">
<f:validator validatorId="urlValidator"/>
    <f:validateRegex pattern="(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message style="color:red" for="URL"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I have Url validator regular expression is `"(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?"`
The following is working in JavaScript but not working in JSF

Comment: The XML-based language you are using there is not XHTML.

Comment: @Quentin hi please update me how write regular Expression in jsf.

Comment: I've no idea what JSF is. Try editing your question so it mentions it and has the right tags.

Comment: Why are you nesting validators?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161040/how-to-validate-string-input-field-for-pattern-on-jsf-form