# JSF Primefaces: Update a dataTable open in another tab?

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have a simple webapp which allows the user to create transactions, and on another page the user can see all past transactions. I would like:

- To have the dataTable be up-to-date when I open the past transaction page
- To update the dataTable when I create a transaction on the creation page

I am not sure if this can be covered by one or two functionalities. Also, I am not sure how to decouple the functionalities. Should the creation of a **transaction trigger the refresh of the dataTable**, or should the **dataTable itself** find new entries in the DB ?

**The past transactions page:**

**My TransactionListModel**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import entity.Transaction;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TransactionListModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Transaction> txList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        txList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTxList() {
        return txList;
    }

    public void clearList(){
        txList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    }
}
```

**My Transaction view**

```
<!-- Fill the table before rendering -->
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="# {transactionListController.findAllTx()}" />

<h:form id="alltxform">
    <p:dataTable id="tableAllTransactions" var="transaction"
                value="#{transactionListModel.txList}">
        <f:facet name="header">Transactions</f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{transaction.id}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**My TransactionList Controller**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TransactionListController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @Inject
    private TransactionService txService;

    @Inject
    private TransactionListModel txListModel;

    public void findAllTx() {
        txListModel.clearList();
        txListModel.getTxList().addAll(txService.findAllTx());
    }

    public void reset() {
        if (txListModel.getTxList() != null) {
            txListModel.clearList();
        }
    }
}
```

**The creation page**

There is a simple textInputField (bound to a model) with a button:

```
<h:commandButton id="sendtx" value="Send" styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{transactionXmlController.sendTx()}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The called method:

```
public void sendTx() {

        FacesMessage message;
        if (!transactionService.sendTx(transactionXmlEditableModel.getXml()).equals("OK"))
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "KO");
        else {
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", "OK");

        }    
        fc.addMessage(null, message);
    }
```

So far, this works.

**My Questions**

- How do I reload the dataTable with AJAX ?
- I would like the dataTable to update even if it has been opened in another tab before the creation of a new transaction. How to do this ?
- How to replace my "f:event type="preRenderView" with a viewAction in order to fill the dataTable before rendering the page ?

Comment: Best way is to use a 'push' mechanism based e.g. on websockets

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would update the table in another tab, without something like `<p:poll>` but to update your table with Ajax you can do something like:

```
<h:commandButton id="sendtx" value="Send" styleClass="ui-priority-primary">
    <f:ajax listener = '#{transactionXmlController.sendTx()}' render="alltxform:tableAllTransactions" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: So effectively your answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138488/how-to-use-ajax-with-jsf-2-0?, but you update the component IN the same page, totally not related to any other tab, so no relation to the real question...

Comment: @Kukeltje question one: how do i reload table with ajax. I mentioned p:poll for the other tab.

Comment: Yes, but that is why I mentioned your answer is identical to the link I posted. Better to refer the user to that other post then in a comment.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: I didn't know that answer exsisted.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I get this error: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'alltxform:tableAllTransactions' - cannot locate it in the context of the component sendtx. Can I use targets that are on other pages in JSF ? The table to update is on another page than the submit button