# JSF Primefaces: How to reference an ID from one page to another?

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Before you mark this as duplicate, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo) post from BalusC but I could not find my answer. I also tried p:component() to reference my component.

**My use case is really simple:**

A commandButton on one page should update a dataTable on another page.

**My caller page:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="sendtxform">
                <h:commandButton id="sendtx" value="Send">
            <f:ajax listener='#{transactionXmlController.sendTx()}'
                render=":alltxform:tablealltx"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**My called page:**

```
<h:body>

<!-- Fill the table before rendering -->
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{transactionListController.findAllTx()}" />

    <h:form id="alltxform">
        <p:dataTable id="tablealltx" var="transaction"
            value="#{transactionListModel.txList}" paginator="true" rows="30">
            <!-- content -->
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**I am getting this error:**

*contains an unknown id ':alltxform:tablealltx' - cannot locate it in the context of the component sendtx*

How on earth do I reference my tablealltx ? I tried with and without the heading colon, and with p:component('tablealltx') What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried to update your wrapper `alltxform` instead of `tablealltx`?

Comment: Just tried. Same error. But I want to update the dataTable, why would I try to update its container ?

Comment: Because, as far as I know, the inner elemets will be updated as well.
Have you tried to update the componente by <p:remoteCommand>? Also, try to update the component by backing bean: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("foo:bar");`

Comment: But it should work without. I have not tried that yet. I would like to understand where my error is.

Comment: Obviously you use Primefaces. Why don't you use the `update` function on your `commandButton`? Not sure how f:ajax works in this context.

Comment: Well, that worked. But I am puzzled. This means the name resolution is not the same for update and render ? Or is render exclusively for elements that are on the same page ?

Comment: This seems like a legit answer but no garantue. I think this is worth an own question :) glad that it works now!

Comment: It are two completely separate pages and not a single page? Basically, you're sending a redirect from one to other page? In other words, a full page reload occurs? In that case the whole `render` and `update` stuff is unnecessary and you can simply remove it.

Comment: @BalusC Do you have any idea why Primefaces update works and f:ajax render doesn't? Is it because there are two different pages?

Comment: Because it doesn't throw an exception anymore in more recent versions. In other words, it's silently ignored. You could as good just remove it.

Comment: My question came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396575/jsf-primefaces-update-a-datatable-open-in-another-tab for which I still don't have a god answer. This one can be closed I guess.